# Argument Out of range exception Error

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

until yesterday the below code was workig fine but today I'm getting a error message Argument out of exception & index out of range.

Wha t i'm tryring to do here, from the `index 3(4th col)` of the last row,  take that cell value & put in to the `col 3 (index 2) cell`. When i type it in the last cell (from bottom to top), i'm getting the above error message.

Please help me.

```
private void datagridview_CellValidated(object sender, CellValidatedEventArgs e)
{

if (e.ColumnIndex != 3)
    return;
int nextRowIndex = e.RowIndex -1;
int lastRowIndex = datagridview.Rows.Count;
try
{

        if (nextRowIndex <= lastRowIndex)
        {
            var valuesForcell = datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            datagridview.Rows[nextRowIndex].Cells[2].Value = valuesForcell;
            datagridview.Rows[nextRowIndex].Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
            datagridview.Rows[nextRowIndex].Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.MediumVioletRed;
            datagridview.ClearSelection();
            datagridview.SelectionMode = GridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
            datagridview.Rows[nextRowIndex].Cells[3].BeginEdit();

        }

}
catch (Exception exception) { }


}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Instead of `nextRowIndex <= lastRowIndex` try `nextRowIndex < lastRowIndex`

Comment: what should happen when you set cell value with index 0? In your example you set `45` in it

Comment: I start from the last cell of the col 3, then last cell of the col 4, then goes up till the end of the last cell in col 4(from bottom to top)

Comment: do you have headers in your table? what `RowIndex` corresponds to first datarow (where `45` resides)?

Comment: 4th col last cell from bottom.

Comment: ok... one more rectification please: can you tell what value does `nextRowIndex` have when error is raised?

Comment: please mark trippino answer as correct answer to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand well you should have:

```
private void datagridview_CellValidated(object sender, CellValidatedEventArgs e)
{

if (e.ColumnIndex != 3)
    return;
int nextRowIndex = e.RowIndex -1;
try
{

        if (nextRowIndex >=0 )
        {
            var valuesForcell = datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            datagridview.Rows[nextRowIndex].Cells[2].Value = valuesForcell;
            datagridview.Rows[nextRowIndex].Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
            datagridview.Rows[nextRowIndex].Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.MediumVioletRed;
            datagridview.ClearSelection();
            datagridview.SelectionMode = GridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
            datagridview.Rows[nextRowIndex].Cells[3].BeginEdit();

        }

}
catch (Exception exception) { }


}
```

You are moving values bottom-up right?

Comment: can you evaluate the variable nextRowIndex?

Comment: There is some confusion here, are you sure you have pasted all the code above? If you did, can you evaluate the variable "nextRowIndex" when the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

If `e.RowIndex` returns you `0` first row, then your `nextRowIndex` will be set to `-1` which is wrong.

also your `lastRowIndex` should be one less than the Row count.

```
int lastRowIndex = datagridview.Rows.Count - 1;
```

I see that you are not referencing the row on `lastRowIndex`, you may modify your check to:

```
if (nextRowIndex < lastRowIndex)
```

Comment: @linguini, Why are you setting the nextRowIndex to e.RowIndex -1 ? what if the e.RowIndex is 0 ? means the first row is selected ?

Comment: I want to start with the last row.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are validating a cell in the 0th row, so the `nextRowIndex` evaluates as `-1`, which is obviously not a valid array index.

Comment: I think that if you're editing the cells from bottom to top, your condition should look like `if(nextRowIndex >= 0)`. And you don't need the `lastRowIndex` at all, because the event args `RowIndex` will always be in the array range.

Answer (score 1):

change your `if` statement to something like this:

```
 if ((nextRowIndex < lastRowIndex) && (nextRowIndex >= -1))
```

`-1` is valid rowIndex  if you want to include even the `Rowheader`.

If you dont want to include `RowHeader` then replace `-1` with `0`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, but thats not the behaviour, when i type in the lat cell of the 4th col, put that vale in the top cell of the adjacent cell

Comment: @linguini try adjusting by giving or removing `-1` somewhere(I dont know where to give or remove it). Understand first what you are doing. Let me try here too.

Comment: I found it, `int nextRowIndex = e.RowIndex-1;if (nextRowIndex >= 0)`

Comment: isn't it the same solution I wrote 30 mins ago? O_o

Comment: trippino refers to previous linguini's comment

Answer (score 0):

When your `e.RowIndex` is `0`, `nextRowIndex` is `-1` and you are trying to access

```
datagridview.Rows[-1].Cells[2].Value = valuesForcell;
```

which throws the Exception